# How to creat nested divisions with different Controller (AngularJs)?

Tags: angularjs

How can I create "div" element inside another "div",and others in the same level **dynamically**!

[This image shows what I am trying to accomplish] https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQyK7.jpg
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/AQyK7.jpg]

The problem is when i want to add "GrianContenu" the console show for me that the function GrainContenu() is undefined but it's work with the "Division".

Can someone help me to add My elements EXACTLY like is shown in the picture.

Here are my app.html, app.js and rightClickDirective.app

**app.js**

```
angular.module("Webapp", ["ngSanitize","directive.contextMenu"])



    .controller("DivisionCtrl", function($scope) {
        $scope.divisions = [{id: 'division1'}];

      $scope.addNewDivision = function() {
        $scope.divisions.push({id: 'division' + ($scope.divisions.length+1)});
      };

    })

    .controller('GrainContenuCtrl', function($scope) {

        $scope.grainContenus = [{'id': 'grainContenu1'}];
        $scope.addNewGrainContenu = function() {
             $scope.grainContenus.push({'id': 'grainContenu' + ($scope.grainContenus.length+1)});  
        };
    })

    .controller('RightClickCtrl', function($scope) {
      $scope.clicked = '';
      $scope.GrainContenu = function() {
        $scope.clicked = $scope.addNewGrainContenu();

      };

      $scope.Division = function() {
        $scope.clicked = $scope.addNewDivision();

      };

      $scope.QCU = function() {
        $scope.clicked = 'link was clicked';

      };

      $scope.QCM = function() {
        $scope.clicked = 'delete was clicked';

      };
    });
```

**rightClickDirective.js**

```
(function(angular) {
  var ngContextMenu = angular.module('directive.contextMenu', []);

  ngContextMenu.directive('cellHighlight', function() {
    return {
      restrict: 'C',
      link: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs) {
        iElement.find('td')
          .mouseover(function() {
            $(this).parent('tr').css('opacity', '0.7');
          }).mouseout(function() {
            $(this).parent('tr').css('opacity', '1.0');
          });
      }
    };
  });

  ngContextMenu.directive('context', [

    function() {
      return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: '@&',
        compile: function compile(tElement, tAttrs, transclude) {
          return {
            post: function postLink(scope, iElement, iAttrs, controller) {
              var ul = $('#' + iAttrs.context),
                last = null;

              ul.css({
                'display': 'none'
              });
              $(iElement).bind('contextmenu', function(event) {
                event.preventDefault();
                 ul.css({
                  position: "fixed",
                  display: "block",
                  left: event.clientX + 'px',
                  top: event.clientY + 'px'
                });
                last = event.timeStamp;
              });
              //$(iElement).click(function(event) {
              //  ul.css({
              //    position: "fixed",
              //    display: "block",
              //    left: event.clientX + 'px',
              //    top: event.clientY + 'px'
              //  });
              //  last = event.timeStamp;
              //});

              $(document).click(function(event) {
                var target = $(event.target);
                if (!target.is(".popover") && !target.parents().is(".popover")) {
                  if (last === event.timeStamp)
                    return;
                  ul.css({
                    'display': 'none'
                  });
                }
              });
            }
          };
        }
      };
    }
  ]);
})(window.angular);
```

**app.html**

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="Webapp" ng-controller="DivisionCtrl">

    <h1>Module Opale</h1>
    Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
    Metadonnées<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
    Objectif du module<input type="text" placeholder="Objectif">

        <div ng-controller="RightClickCtrl" context="context1">
        <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="division in divisions" ng-controller="GrainContenuCtrl">
            <h2>Division</h2>
            Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre">
            <br />Titre court
            <input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
                <div class="form-group" data-ng-repeat="grainContenu in grainContenus">

                    <h3>Grain de Contenu</h3>
                    Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
                    Titre court<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
                    <h4>Information</h4>
                    Titre<input type="text" placeholder="Titre"><br />
                    <textarea rows="4" cols="50"></textarea><br />
                </div>
            <hr />
            </div>

            <ul id="context1" class="dropdown-menu">
              <li><a ng-click="GrainContenu()">Grain de Contenu</a></li>
              <li><a ng-click="Division()">Division</a></li>
              <li><a ng-click="QCU()">Exercice:QCU</a></li>
              <li><a ng-click="QCM()">Exercice:QCM</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    <script type="text/javascript"    src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.3.15/angular-sanitize.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/app.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/rightClickDirective.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/jquery/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js/plugins/bootstrap/bootstrap.min.js"></script>   
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: too much code..please refactor it and add relevant code only..its very hard to read

Comment: Do you need it infinitely nesteable?

Comment: Yes @Dmitri Zaitsev,infinitely neasteable

Answer (score 0):

I have created a plunker recreating the above snippet. The issue it would seem is that your current hierarchy of controllers is

```
-DivisionController
  |-RightClickCtrl (has no idea about GrainContenu)
  |  |--GrainContenuCtrl (GrainContenu)
  |- etc...
```

The function `GrainContenu` is defined within the `GrainContenuCtrl`. The 'RightClickCtrl' has no idea that it exists (not exactly true since you could traverse the `$scope` hierarchy to find - which in my opinion is not ideal)

The [**Plunker**](http://plnkr.co/edit/EBR5gh8PyiLngVWMIMfC?p=preview) simply simply moves the 'GrainContenuCtrl' above the 'RightClickCtrl' so that `RightClickCtrl` no prototypically  inherits from  `GrainContenuCtrl` thus allowing it to have access to the `GrainContenu` function.

```
-DivisionController
  |--GrainContenuCtrl (GrainContenu)
  |   |-RightClickCtrl (prototypically inherits from GrainContenuCtrl ) 
  |- etc...
```

The answer to [What are the nuances of scope prototypal / prototypical inheritance in AngularJS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/14049482/268667) for more info around Prototypical Inheritance in AngularJS